# Input Voltage LM8560

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I am currently building a digital clock using the [LM8560](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.paulanders.com/G5-LED/ver1/datablad.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwixzo71o_zsAhWlM-wKHaVGBZkQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1vXx7_ZOnxj-WnshGdH0AT).

In the datasheet it says the maximum voltage at each Pin should not exceed +0.3V or -15V. The IC uses the line frequency of 50/60Hz, which is connected to Pin 25 from one of the transformers secondary windings. I am using a 2x 7V transformer with center tap.
But because its AC wouldn't the voltage at the input pin be +9.8V and -9.8V?
Is this ok to do so, or am I missing something in the datasheet?

Comment: The data sheet says that VDD is -15 to -7.5. The 50/60Hz inputs are limited between -1 and VDD+2 which is -1 to -5.5. So no you can not directly connect your transformer output to the pins without damaging the chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the **application diagram** in the datasheet and notice that there's a 100 kohm resistor between the transformer and pin 25 of the LM5860:

[image]

Do note that this IC and its circuit is a bit unconventional, VSS = grounded which is normal but VDD is a **negative supply voltage** which is uncommon these days. This was more common in the 1970s and early 1980s though. This LM5860 is made in "P-channel ED MOS LSI" technology which is **ancient** so that could explain this.

In this circuit the center tap of the transformer is grounded so the voltage going to the 50/60 Hz input will not fit in the -15 V to +0.3 V. **But** it doesn't matter! The IC very likely has internal clamping diodes which are needed for ESD protection, these diodes can operate in forward mode as long as the **current is limited** (to for example less than 1 mA, that's just my educated guess).

This is where that 100 kohm resistor comes in, even if the transformer delivers a voltage that is larger than -15 V to + 0.3 V, the resistor will **limit the current** to a safe level so **no damage is done**.

It is not a very "elegant" way to limit the input voltage to pin but it works. A more elegant way would be to something like this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fejmZR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where the 1 k resistor and the 5.6 V zener diode limit the voltage to -5.6 V to + 0.7 V which exceeds the + 0.3 V maximum but again there is a 100 k ohm resistor to limit the current so nothing bad can happen.

It is unclear to me what the detection level of the 50/60 Hz input is, maybe it needs a higher voltage than -5.6 V, you could use a 12 V zener diode in that case. But first try the solution using only a 100 k resistor as that will probably work well enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I understand it now. I just noticed in the datasheet that the maximum input clamp current is +/- 0.4 mA.

Comment: *maximum input clamp current is +/- 0.4 mA.* With that 100 k resistor you would need 40 V across the resistor to get that current. So the +/- 10 V from your transformer with the 100 k resistor will ensure that the current is low enough, maximum 0.1 mA.